# OpenGL Extensions in Qt 4

Tags: opengl, qt4

it's possible enable/use OpenGL (specific version) in Qt 4 (on Desktop) or I have to use glew, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt has wrappers for some extentions like QPixelBuffers otherwise you can just use glew to enable the extentions

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Glew you can include [gl3.h](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/gl3.h&rct=j&q=gl3.h&ei=rGeIToO-FqKsiAeJsqmTDw&usg=AFQjCNEv6k83xQMT2Y0FJywfZhfKmLXzww&sig2=gJIUm_Or4BtlmEaTEeej7g), it's probably the simplest and most pain free way and works with compatibility mode as well as core. It's also well worth checking out [GLXX](https://bitbucket.org/yotis/glxx/wiki/Home) it's a newer lib written in C++ so its more object orientated and provides handy functions for querying capabilities and so on.

You could look at manually binding just the extensions you need, possibly making your own Qt classes.

Other alternatives are [Glee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) (A bit out of date now, only up to OpenGL 3.0) and [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) (a script to generate header files for you, but only seems to support OpenGL 3/4 core).

Also if you want a object orientated library for OpenGL itself [OGLplus](http://kifri.fri.uniza.sk/~chochlik/oglplus/html/) looks good, doesn't do extensions though.

Answer (score 0):

My way to do that (Windows)... You need [www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h)

I'm using this [python script](https://github.com/martadrlik/python-scripts/blob/master/mkglex.py) to generate glex.h (p_glext.h) and glex.cpp from glext.h

p_glext.h is copy of glext.h without prototypes.

```
//glex.h
#ifndef GLEX_H
#define GLEX_H

#include "p_glext.h"

extern void glexInit();
extern PFNGLBLENDCOLORPROC glBlendColor;
extern PFNGLBLENDEQUATIONPROC glBlendEquation;
extern PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC glDrawRangeElements;
...

//glex.cpp
...
void glexInit() {
    glBlendColor = (PFNGLBLENDCOLORPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBlendColor");
    glBlendEquation = (PFNGLBLENDEQUATIONPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBlendEquation");
    glDrawRangeElements = (PFNGLDRAWRANGEELEMENTSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glDrawRangeElements");
...
}
```

that's simple enough to me